# Can I write this about eyes?

Tags: meaning, writing

I looked into her egocentric eyes and told her to get lost.

Is it okay to use this kind of adjective before eyes? thanks

Comment: Yes, the condtruction is what is known as a transferred epithet: From "ThoughCo" https://www.thoughtco.com/transferred-epithet-1692558 *A transferred epithet is a [...] figure of speech in which a modifier (usually an adjective) qualifies a noun other than the person or thing it is actually describing. In other words, the modifier or epithet is transferred from the noun it is meant to describe to another noun in the sentence.* e.g. "The lonely night"; "wide-eyed amazement" "He pointed an angry finger at me." the night is not lonely, the amazement not wide-eyed, the finger not angry.

Comment: @Greybeard - Uh, what is a "condtruction"?

Comment: @Hot Licks; never mind what it is. How does one pronounce it? @Manassah; Yes, you can right any old thing to describe those eyes, either one or both. It seems she has it coming.

Comment: @Elliot - Write you are!

Comment: @H.L. Many thanks. You do have the right to write. And here we write right. (I'm going to be sick)